# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields LOOP posts ACF by values

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress website where i want to use ACF for displaying some posts/pages by the values putted in, for example:

Lets say that i have 3 pages:

1st page with ACF text field value "asd"

2nd page with ACF text field value "asd" and selective field "123"

3rd page with ACF text field value "qwe"

I want to make a loop which it will display all pages which contains the ACF text value "asd" AND selective field "123". The result must display only the 2nd page.

In the end, I will try to make an advanced "search" form by only ticking some boxes and selecting some predefined texts from a list and so on, displaying me only the posts/pages with those ACF values

Can someone please tell me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *clears throat* "We are not a code writing service". Please provide information on what you have already tried.

Comment: sorry then :( i was trying to find just the proper portion of code, not the complete website

Comment: Please take a look at this page and update your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask due to the nature and volume of StackOverFlow only some question types are allowed. Best of luck!